# Attempting To Find A Way To Block Internet Explorer Users From Opening My Page While I Fix Issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a site that I just published and have just found a bunch of compatibility problems with Internet Explorer (surprise surprise!). I was on a time crunch and would like to keep the site up since it looks great on all other browsers but prevent people running Internet Explorer to see the site and give them a default splash page (if possible) while I work on the compatibility issues..

Is there a way to do this? I thought about using the conditional statements for the style sheets and maybe editing it that way but I thought I'd see if anyone knew of an easy way to do it.

Comment: That sounds like an awful idea. Give them the site, but give them a notice apologising for having to give them a broken version.

Comment: @lonesome: id say that depends. IF for example this is a portfolio site or something it might be fine to just a have splash page up for the time being - like the site has never launched. Id say thats better than having it in a disastrous state and apologizing for it... especially if hes going to havit fixed in the short term.

Comment: Perhaps. Personally, I'd want you to say (a) you can view the page if you really want to (you can't stop me) and (b) give us your email address and we'll let you know if it's fixed. If it's not *totally* unusable, that is...

Comment: I did end up taking the site down completely and putting a splash page up for everyone (I ended up having more compatibility issues than I initially thought). That being said, I know how to do this now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use IE-only conditionals and display a overlay over the whole page, see [here for conditionals](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) . In your ie-only code you'd display something like this :

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <div style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background:white;padding-top:50%;text-align:center;'>
          <!-- add more styling or split it up in some separate stylesheet-->
          This site is currently disabled for IE users
   </div>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, it would seem to be that you're going to have to query the client's browser user agent and redirect/load the appropriate page/CSS as per the result.  Seems like a conditional statement is the way I would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is called "browser sniffing" and is generally thought of as a not-very-elegant way to attack this kind of problem. But it is useful.

Quirksmode has arguably [the best library](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) for this. You stick the big object below into a script and query it using these three attributes:

```
BrowserDetect.browser
BrowserDetect.version
BrowserDetect.OS
```

Full object source (see Quirksmode for more information):

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

place a ie detection before  like
this is for ie 6

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link href="css/disposeIE6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

then inside css/dispose.ie.css

```
body{
display:        block; width:1024px; height:768px;
background:     transparent url(../disposeIE6.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

then make a 'disposeIE6.jpg' with your message. this will cover the site at the dimensions 1024px X 768px

Comment: Why IE6 only? What about other versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Apache you could do this with a single .htaccess file in the root.

1) Make and IE.html file. -  saying something like "This site is current undergoing work, please try again later."
2) And create a .htaccess file in the root of your site and paste the text below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 6"  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 7"  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 8"  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 9"
RewriteRule (.*) IE.html
```